# Tor Cookie Manager

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cookies

How do you white list certain cookies in TOR? I know TOR by default keeps cookies until you exit window but is there a way to make it delete cookies till x amount of time after a tab is closed from the origin of the cookie? Do you have to use a browser extension for that if so what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to make it delete cookies till x amount of time after a tab is closed from the origin of the cookie

No

> Do you have to use a browser extension for that

Yes

> what do you recommend?

Not installing browser extensions. They can make you more easily fingerprintable.

Comment: Also Tor Browser runs in private browsing mode, which doesn't give you access to cookies in that manner, so cookie manager extensions won't work.